# rotation transform (storyBoard animation) property path issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, storyboard, transformation

i am getting an `error` when setting the `property path` for `rotation transform` for a `button`
**error** ->  **Cannot resolve TargetProperty (UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Rotation) on specified object.**

the c# code is ->

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Rotation)"));
```

the xaml is ->

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Content="request" Click="btn_Click">
     <Button.RenderTransform>
               <RotateTransform CenterX="0" />
     </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

is it a path error or something else and if path than what will be the correct path ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RotateTransform` object directly. Just call it somehow in XAML, for example:

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Content="request" Click="btn_Click">
     <Button.RenderTransform>
               <RotateTransform x:Nam="BtnRotation" CenterX="0" />
     </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

In code behind:

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, BtnRotation);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("CenterX"));
```